# Embedded SWF file - how to hide play bar

Tags: html, flash

I have a swf file I am embedding into a webpage.  The file should play as soon as the page opens.  Everything works fine EXCEPT that I need to hide the play/control bar that is at the bottom of the video.  The HTML I am using is:

```
<embed id="media" src="#WORKSPACE_IMAGES#VisionSelling/VisionSellingV1.swf"
width="960" height="626" quality="best" bgcolor="#4A4A4A" 
allowScriptAccess="always" allowFullScreen="true" wmode="window" 
type="application/x-shockwave-flash" 
pluginspace="http://get.adobe.comflashplayer/">
```

I have seen references to a CONTROLS setting, but it just said to NOT include this parameter if you do not wants controls...

Comment: did you try setting skinAutoHide=true; ?

Comment: I had not, but adding it does not seem to make any difference.

Answer (score 0):

I have not been able to find a way via code to do this, however, in the GENERATION of the swf file, there is a way.  The tool I am using is Tanaida Demo Builder, and there is a parameter that says to NOT show the play bar.  This will work for what I want.